# Python nlp spacy OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'de'

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I installed spacy with pip and wanted to load spacy. The following python code with spacy:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('de',disable=['parser', 'tagger','ner'])

nlp.max_length = 1198623
```

Unfortunately, the code is throwing the following error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'de'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install spacy as the following:

```
python -m spacy download de
```